# How do I access the R squared value for the entire model generated by vegan function envfit?

Tags: r, vegan

I am analyzing some microbiome data by using unconstrained ordination (PCA or NMDS) followed by environmental vector fitting with the envfit function in the vegan package. The output of envfit includes an r2 value for each vector or factor included in the envfit model, but I am interested in the total amount of variation explained by all the vectors/factors, rather than just stand-alone variables. I presume I cannot simply add up the R2 values assigned to each environmental variable, because there may be overlap in the microbiome variation that is "explained" by each environmental variable. However, there does not seem to be any way of accessing the total r2 value for the model.

Using an example dataset, this is what I have tried so far:

```
library(vegan)
library(MASS)

data(varespec, varechem)
library(MASS)
ord <- metaMDS(varespec)
fit <- envfit(ord, varechem, perm = 999)
fit
```

This shows r2 for each environmental variable, but how do I extract the r2 value for the entire model?

I have tried running fit$r, attributes(fit)$r, and Rsquare.Adj(fit), but these all return NULL.

Comment: Hi, could you please always post reproducible code on Stack Overflow? 1. Your `library` call is missing, 2. `cca()` will only work for numeric columns. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! This is my first post, so just learning the ropes. I'll make the change.

Comment: I also updated my question to include a dataset that is closer to my own, and used NMDS rather than CCA, yielding output that is more similar to my actual analysis.

Comment: Now it's a great question, I have no idea though :)

Comment: You have to consider each environmental variable separately. Because they have different scales, you cannot calculate R^2 which is 1 - SSE / SST. For example, try this summary(lm(cbind(mpg,wt) ~.,data=mtcars))

Comment: You can see that the r^2 is calculated different for each response..

Comment: Thanks for that info/example, StupidWolf. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? (I think that's how this works -?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R-squared = Explained variation / Total variation, or r^2 = 1 - SSE/SST. For two different responses, the residuals will be on different scales, so calculating a combined R^2 for two responses does not make sense.

For example, in classical lm, they are calculated separately:

```
> summary(lm(cbind(mpg,wt) ~.,data=mtcars))
Response mpg :

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + qsec + vs + am + 
    gear + carb, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.6453 -1.2655 -0.4199  1.6320  5.0843 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 15.57062   19.81294   0.786   0.4403  
cyl          0.11982    1.10348   0.109   0.9145  
disp        -0.01361    0.01212  -1.122   0.2738  
hp          -0.01122    0.02246  -0.500   0.6223  
drat         1.32726    1.71312   0.775   0.4467  
qsec         0.09428    0.66944   0.141   0.8893  
vs           0.66770    2.22845   0.300   0.7673  
am           2.90074    2.17590   1.333   0.1961  
gear         1.18650    1.56061   0.760   0.4552  
carb        -1.32912    0.63321  -2.099   0.0475 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.816 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.845, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7816 
F-statistic: 13.33 on 9 and 22 DF,  p-value: 5.228e-07


Response wt :

Call:
lm(formula = wt ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + qsec + vs + am + gear + 
    carb, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.40769 -0.18831  0.00012  0.15204  0.50382 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.879401   2.098183  -0.419 0.679189    
cyl         -0.062246   0.116858  -0.533 0.599603    
disp         0.007252   0.001284   5.649 1.11e-05 ***
hp          -0.002763   0.002378  -1.162 0.257792    
drat        -0.145385   0.181419  -0.801 0.431483    
qsec         0.195613   0.070893   2.759 0.011445 *  
vs          -0.094189   0.235992  -0.399 0.693653    
am          -0.102418   0.230427  -0.444 0.661045    
gear        -0.142945   0.165268  -0.865 0.396411    
carb         0.304068   0.067056   4.535 0.000163 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2983 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9341,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9071 
F-statistic: 34.63 on 9 and 22 DF,  p-value: 5.944e-11
```

For this example, you have to calculate each R^2 for each environment variable